# Difference between closure of A and A?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

["The closure of a set A is the smallest closed set containing A."](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetClosure.html)

But if A is closed, then isn't the closure of A = A?

Or is the notion of closure only used for open and half-open/-closed sets, since this way one can consider the closure of such set, say B, which is not equal to B, but has B as its subset.

Comment: For some sets $A$, indeed $\overline A = A$. For all sets $A$, we have $\overline{\overline A} = \overline A$. The power of the concept lies in it applying to any set.

Comment: $\overline{A}=A$ holds exactly when $A$ is closed.

Comment: What is the absolute value of a positive number? Does is make sense to talk about it?

Comment: "If A is closed, then isn't the closure of A = A?" Yes.

Answer (score 4):

If $A$ is closed, then you are correct that it is its own closure. For that reason, you would be unlikely to talk about "the closure of $A$" when you knew beforehand that $A$ was closed.

But you might talk about it when $A$ was an unknown set that might or might not be closed. So it's still important to know how the definition of closure works for already-closed sets.

Answer (score 0):

Closure is a property that any set can have, same as interior. A closed set is a set that A satisfies cl(A) = A, so in that case you can treat A as the set itself or as the closure and it doesn't matter, but sometimes, for an unknown set, the closure can be quite important. For example, if A is dense in X, then cl(A) = X, and that is true weather A is is closed, open, clopen, or non of the above.